# HTTP requests are tampered by other HTTP requests, with golang and standard library

Tags: rest, go, webserver

cat main.go:

```

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/fcgi"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    //setup the config
    configFile := "config.json"
    fd, err := os.Open(configFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't open config file: %v", configFile)
    }
    CFG := config{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(fd).Decode(&CFG)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("parse config error: %v", err)
    }

    //init DB connection
    db.InitConnectionInfo(CFG.Database.Host, CFG.Database.Port, CFG.Database.Database, CFG.Database.Username, CFG.Database.Password)

    //register HTTP handler
    sessionHandler := &handlers.SessionHandler{}
    http.Handle("/sessions", sessionHandler)
    http.Handle("/sessions/", sessionHandler)

    userHandler := &handlers.UserHandler{
        Facebook:      &oa.OAuth{AppId: CFG.Facebook.Key, Secret: CFG.Facebook.Secret},
        Sina:          &oa.OAuth{AppId: CFG.Sina.Key, Secret: CFG.Sina.Secret},
        Google:        &oa.OAuth{AppId: CFG.Google.Key, Secret: CFG.Google.Secret},
        Tencent:       &oa.OAuth{AppId: CFG.Tencent.Key, Secret: CFG.Tencent.Secret},
        Mixpanel:      &hu.Share{Token: CFG.Mixpanel.Token},
        FacebookShare: &hu.Share{Token: CFG.Facebook.Token},
        SinaShare:     &hu.Share{Token: CFG.Sina.Token},
        GoogleShare:   &hu.Share{Token: CFG.Google.Token},
        TencentShare:  &hu.Share{Token: CFG.Tencent.Token},
    }
    http.Handle("/users", userHandler)
    http.Handle("/users/", userHandler)

    //and so on ...

    //run server
    log.Println("start listen: ", CFG.FcgiAddr)
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", CFG.FcgiAddr)
    log.Fatalf("server error is %v", fcgi.Serve(l, nil))
    //@@select {}
    log.Println("end listen")
}
```

```

build it and deploy behind nginx.

then client query `/users/1234567/places`, `/users/1234567`, and so on...

get the response is `{blank data}`, `{normal user(1234567) data}` or `{normal user(1234567) data}`, `{normal user(1234567) data}`.

same prefix of query, and same handler, looks like it is overload the response by subsequent HTTP request.

How can I do it?

May need me to give an example of a response:

correct response is :

`{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "text": "OK"
    },
    "data": {
        "count": 21,
        "place-tag-maps": [{
            "id": "95842310160384",
            "place-id": "95551731663150",
            "tag-id": "95551579750669",
            "ct": "2014-07-01T09:07:28Z"
        }, {
            "id": "95842310160385",
            "place-id": "95551731663150",
            "tag-id": "95551579750694",
            "ct": "2015-01-15T17:41:23Z"
        }, {
            "id": "96262389694470",
            "place-id": "95551731663150",
            "tag-id": "95910120456455",
            "ct": "2016-07-18T13:11:39Z"
        }, ...],
        "places": [{
            "id": "95551731663150",
            "name": "Kam Fung Restaurant",
            "address": "G/F, 41 Spring Garden Ln",
            "coordinate": {
                "latitude": 22.275576,
                "longitude": 114.172582
            },
            "telephone": "+852 2572 0526",
            "city-id": "95530516807703",
            "city": "Hong Kong",
            "country": "Hong Kong",
            "type": "4sq",
            "ref-id": "4b1613f8f964a520cdb623e3",
            "ct": "2016-02-23T07:42:43.565489Z",
            "mt": "2017-02-22T09:35:48.302929Z",
            "rating": 7.5,
            "stats": {
                "foursquare": {
                    "count": 111,
                    "value": 7.5
                },
                "spottly": {
                    "save-count": 12
                }
            },
            "permanent-close": false,
            "price": ""
        }, ...],
        "posts": [{
            "collection-id": "95551746474003",
            "coordinate": {
                "latitude": 22.275576,
                "longitude": 114.172582
            },
            "ct": "2017-02-22T09:35:47Z",
            "facebook-tag-users": [],
            "id": "97501586849795",
            "medias": [],
            "message": "",
            "mt": "2017-02-22T09:35:47Z",
            "owner-id": "96527264645120",
            "place-id": "95551731663150",
            "share-to": [],
            "star": 5,
            "status": "Done",
            "tags": []
        }, ...],
        "users": [{
            "id": "95551581323446",
            "uid": "hk_epicurus",
            "uid-ignore-case": "hk_epicurus",
            "name": "Hk Epicurus",
            "head": "https://d278wa0j9nq2mp.cloudfront.net/uploader/54aa335ddf4e63450002919a.jpeg",
            "site": "www.hkepicurus.com",
            "location": "Hong Kong",
            "description": "Hong Kong Food \u0026 Travel Bear.\nGrew up in Aust, Malaysia, Tokyo \u0026 HK. \nInstagram: EpicurusHongKong\nFacebook, Spottly \u0026 Twitter: HK Epicurus \n微博: 香港美食-伊比\nFacebook Fans Page:  http://on.fb.me/1qDyiIk",
            "ct": "2013-10-13T19:12:41Z",
            "mt": "2015-11-08T15:22:45Z"
        }, ...]
    }
}`

and

`{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "text": "OK"
    },
    "data": {
        "friends": [{
            "id": "97331335725056",
            "from-id": "97273770803200",
            "to-id": "96527264645120",
            "ct": "2017-01-23T07:58:41Z"
        }],
        "user": {
            "ct": "2013-04-30T23:30:05Z",
            "description": "Founder and Chief Everything Officer of Spottly. Loves to eat. Have a really bad memory. Wants to remember the best places and make travel research better",
            "followers": {
                "count": 41291
            },
            "followings": {
                "count": 322
            },
            "head": "https://d278wa0j9nq2mp.cloudfront.net/uploader/525ffac8df4e6347870145ef.jpeg",
            "id": "96527264645120",
            "location": "Vancouver | Hong Kong | Beijing ",
            "mt": "2015-10-27T09:47:12Z",
            "name": "Edwyn Chan",
            "site": "http://spottly.com/edwyn",
            "uid": "edwyn",
            "uid-ignore-case": "edwyn"
        }
    }
}`

but mistake response is

`{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "text": "OK"
    }
}`

and

`{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "text": "OK"
    },
    "data": {
        "friends": [{
            "id": "97331335725056",
            "from-id": "97273770803200",
            "to-id": "96527264645120",
            "ct": "2017-01-23T07:58:41Z"
        }],
        "user": {
            "ct": "2013-04-30T23:30:05Z",
            "description": "Founder and Chief Everything Officer of Spottly. Loves to eat. Have a really bad memory. Wants to remember the best places and make travel research better",
            "followers": {
                "count": 41291
            },
            "followings": {
                "count": 322
            },
            "head": "https://d278wa0j9nq2mp.cloudfront.net/uploader/525ffac8df4e6347870145ef.jpeg",
            "id": "96527264645120",
            "location": "Vancouver | Hong Kong | Beijing ",
            "mt": "2015-10-27T09:47:12Z",
            "name": "Edwyn Chan",
            "site": "http://spottly.com/edwyn",
            "uid": "edwyn",
            "uid-ignore-case": "edwyn"
        }
    }
}`

the first response is error. or it's same as the second response.

sequence request is correct response, parallel request is incorrect response.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your problem is...

Comment: @AlexanderR.  I append response example for clear the problem

Comment: fcgi is a relic from the 90s, and there's really no good reason to be using it now. It's only adding more unknowns to this already incomplete example.

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved。

the basic reason is this case:

```
var x = &{...} //init value
fillX(..., x) //fill the fields of x pointer 
//here the fields of x pointer is not same to inner of fillX func
```

so, change to

```
var x = &{...}
x = fullX(..., x)
the problem resolved.
```

but why go pointer is the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this problem resolved.

Because the http.Handle register path-pattern and handler pair, the handler is construct by register time only-once, not for any request of path-pattern.

if record info within handler, It will been change by after request.

Comment: Shouldn't this be an update to your existing answer?